# Finding max of $var(a^TY)$.

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, orthonormal, gaussian, bivariate-distributions

Let $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ be a multivariate random variable with the standard Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Define the multivariate random variable $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)^T$ by

$$\begin{pmatrix} Y_1 \\\ Y_2 \\\ Y_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\\ \frac{1}{3} &-\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\\ -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_1 \\\ 2X_2 \\\ X_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I find the maximum value of for $var(a^TY)$ given that $a^Ta = 1$?

I am really struggling with this question, if anyone could help me , I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what is $a$ here?

Comment: It is unclear what "$a$" is in your question.

Comment: @NN2 sorry for the typo. I meant $var(a^TY)$ and $a$ is any vector $(a_1, a_2, a_3)^T$. that satisfies $a^Ta = 1$

Comment: @user changed now

Comment: presumably you mean the max of $\text{var}(a^TY)$.

Comment: @user sorry for the poor wording. I am trying to find the maximum value for $var(a^TY)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found variance of $a^T Y$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am struggling to start this question. How do I get the variance for $a^TY$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the maximum is the maxium value of the eigenvalues of the matrix $M^TM$ where $M$ is the matrix defined by $Y = MX$. The answer is long, I haven't finished it yet so I hide it. I come back later.

Comment: @NN2 does that property change if the X vector for $Y=MX$ has a $2X_2$ instead of just an $X_2$?

Comment: $a^T Y=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i Y_i$. What is its variance?

Comment: The matrix $M$ I said has the first and third line equal to your matrix in the question. Its second line is $(\frac{2}{3},- \frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3})$

Comment: $a_1^2var(Y_1)+a_2^2var(Y_2)+a_3^2var(Y_3)+2a_1a_2cov(Y_1,Y_2)+2a_1a_3⋅cov(Y_1,Y_3)+2a_2a_3⋅cov(Y_2,Y_3)$ is it? @StubbornAtom

Comment: Please edit your question to show some work, whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I solve the more general problem. Let $Y = MX$ with

- $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a standard multivariate Gaussian random variable
- $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a matrix

We find $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that the expression $V(a^TY)$ reaches its maximum with the constraint $a^Ta = 1$.
**Remark**: for your question, $n = 3$, $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$  and
$$M =\begin{pmatrix} 
-\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\\ 
\frac{2}{3} &-\frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} \\\ 
-\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix} $$

---

We have
$$
\begin{align}
V(a^TY) &=V((a^TM)X) \\
 &=V((M^Ta)^TX) \\
&=(M^Ta)^T(M^Ta) \\
&=(M^Ta)^T(M^Ta) \\
&=a^T (MM^T)a \tag{1} \\
\end{align}
$$

The expression $V(a^TY)$ can reach its maximum or not depend on whether the matrix $MM^T$ is positive definite or not. For the matrix in your example, $MM^T$ is well positive definite. So, we can diagonalize this matrix as follows

$$MM^T = U^T D U$$
with $U$ the eigenvectors matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix of eigeinvalues of $MM^T$.

Then from $(1)$
$$
\begin{align}
V(a^TY) &= a^T ( U^T D U)a \\
&= (Ua)^T D(Ua)
\end{align}
$$

The epression $V(a^TY)$ reaches its maximum of the maximum eigenvalue of $M^TM$.

//Not finished yet